# Python3: Trying to check for a duplicate within a list of lists, and then check if another element of that list of lists is also a duplicate

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

I've converted a csv file to a list of lists (each row being a list) and I'm trying to see if an element at index `x` ('2' in my script) of that row is duplicated in any other row. If it *is* duplicated, I need to check if index `y` ('5' in my script) is duplicated as well. I've written the following nested for loop:

```
def duplicate_twice(list_of_lists):
    temp = []
    for i in row_list:
        for j in row_list:
            if row_list[i][2] == row_list[j][2]:
                if row_list[i][5] != row_list[j][5]:
                    diff_part.append(row_list[j])
    return diff_part
```

This makes sense to me logically, but I'm running into `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list`

1. Is there a more pythonic way to execute what I'm working towards?
2. What can I change to get around the TypeError?

Comment: It's python. Here i and j are the elements of your lists, not indices. Consider using pandas to solve your problem. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html

Answer (score 1):

Consider solving this using the Pandas library.
Here is an example, on how this might be solved.

Let's say we have the following dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['John', 'Black', 25], 
                   ['Jack', 'White', 23], 
                   ['Alice', 'Smith', 31], 
                   ['John', 'Black', 44]], 
                  columns=['Name', 'Surname', 'Age'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    Name Surname  Age
0   John   Black   25
1   Jack   White   23
2  Alice   Smith   31
3   John   Black   44
```

Now, let's say we want to find people with the same name and surname.

```
df[df.duplicated(['Name', 'Surname'], False)]  # This will return your duplicates.
```

Consider changing the second parameter (`keep`) of the `duplicated` method based on your needs. It might flag the first appearance of a duplicate, the last, and all appearances in the dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Most pythonic way I can think is here:

```
array = [
    ['a1', 'b1', 'xx', 'd1', 'e1', 'yy'],
    ['a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2', 'e2', 'yy'],
    ['a3', 'b3', 'xx', 'd3', 'e3', 'yy'],
    ['a4', 'b4', 'xx', 'd4', 'e4', 'f4'],
    ['a5', 'b5', 'xx', 'd5', 'e5', 'yy'],
    ['a6', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2', 'e2', 'yy'],
]

# convert the 2d array into an object
# which keys are sum of 2nd and 5th elements of every row of the array

obj = {}
for row in array:
    try:
        obj[row[2] + row[5]].append(row)
    except:
        obj[row[2] + row[5]] = [row]


# get the keys that contain more than one value

duplicated_rows = [ obj[key] for key in obj if len(obj[key]) > 1 ]

print(duplicated_rows)
```

Output:

```
[
    ['a1', 'b1', 'xx', 'd1', 'e1', 'yy'], 
    ['a3', 'b3', 'xx', 'd3', 'e3', 'yy'], 
    ['a5', 'b5', 'xx', 'd5', 'e5', 'yy']
], 
[
    ['a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2', 'e2', 'yy'], 
    ['a6', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2', 'e2', 'yy']
]
```